# Proteger archivo pdf despues de firmarlo con iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Lo que quiero hacer, una vez firmado con un certificado el pdf, protegerlo para que no puedan imprimirlo, ni copiar contenido, ni volver a firmarlo.
He probado con :

```
PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(
    reader,
    new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write),
    true,
    null,
    null,
    PdfWriter.AllowFillIn | PdfWriter.AllowScreenReaders);
```

El error que me da son estos dos:

> iTextSharp.text.DocumentException: 'The original document was reused.
>   Read it again from file.' System.IO.IOException: 'The process can not
>   access the file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.pdf'

Para firmar uso:

```
    public void Sign(string SigReason, string SigContact, string SigLocation, bool visible)
{
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.inputPDF);
    /*ERROR-->*/PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), true, null, null, PdfWriter.AllowFillIn | PdfWriter.AllowScreenReaders);
                PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, true);
                st.MoreInfo = this.metadata.getMetaData();
                st.XmpMetadata = this.metadata.getStreamedMetaData();
                PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;

                sap.SetCrypto(this.myCert.Akp, this.myCert.Chain, null, PdfSignatureAppearance.WINCER_SIGNED);
                sap.Reason = SigReason;
                sap.Contact = SigContact;
                sap.Location = SigLocation;

                if (visible)
                    sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 150), 1, null);

                st.Close();

            }
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936189/itext-disable-printing-copying-saving

Comment: Buenas Diego, he probado pero me lanza el error:
`System.IO.IOException: 'El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\PRUEBA CERT_firmado.pdf' porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.'`

Comment: verifica que dicho archivo "CERT_firmado.pdf" no este abierto en ningun otro lado..!!

Comment: No lo tengo abierto, fíjate en el código que es el archivo que se crea para firmarlo, supongo que por eso no deja darle los permisos... La idea principal es firmar digitalmente el pdf y quitarle permisos de imprimir, copiar o refirmar. gracias.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema. ¿Lo pudiste resolver?